# Парсим XML с атрибутами и значениями с помощью PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser

У меня есть XML файл, как его распарсить с помощью PHP? Обращаю внимание, что у параметра есть и значение и атрибут.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<price currency="EUR"></price>
<phone currency="4.95" >val 1</phone>
<phone currency="5.95" >val 2</phone>
</xml>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-string.php  и поехали парсить))

Comment: Внимательно. Параметр содержит и атрибут, и значение. Поэтому и не парсится.

Comment: А может просто невнимательно мануалы читаете? `simplexml_load_string($str)->price->attributes()->currency`

Comment: А для phone пример сделаете? Как получить и значение и атрибут?

Comment: вы потрудитесь справку то прочесть, значения через `$obj->field` атрибуты через `$obj['attr']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, что удалось вспомнить)

```
$str="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<xml>
<price currency=\"EUR\"></price>
<phone currency=\"4.95\" >val 1</phone>
<phone currency=\"5.95\" >val 2</phone>
</xml>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);

echo $xml->price->attributes()->currency; //читаем атрибут

foreach($xml->phone as $phone){

    echo $phone->attributes()->currency; //читаем атрибут
    echo (string)$phone->{0}; //читаем значение, где {0} - указатель на "первый" элемент

    unset($phone);
}
```

Comment: не усложняйте, `(float) $phone['currency']`

Comment: @teran Вот правильно вообще все говорите

Comment: @teran обычно считывал в потоке, где встречается и текст и с плавающей запятой, поэтому в памяти осталось))

Comment: @DaemonHK я про то, что доступ к атрибуту через квадратные скобки по имени (ну или хз при чем тут вы плавующую точку упомянули)

Comment: @teran подумал что вы про `{0}` )) а по поводу вашего уточнения - привычка работать с объектами, к тому же у ноды может быть несколько атрибутов, которые иногда проще обработать циклом

Comment: Спасибо, работает!